# VSCode doesn't open Merge Editor when merging branches

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, merge, git-merge

Recently, I have been having issues with merging branches. I use the command "Git: Merge branch from..." to select the branch that I want to merge but, when I select it, the merge just overrides all the code from the branch that is receiving the merge instead of opening the merge editor to let me decide if I want to accept all the incoming changes.

PS: In VSCode settings I've check the Merge Editor option.

As I said before, I use the command "Git: Merge branch from..." because every site I visit says that is the correct option procedure, when VSCode should open the Merge Editor, it doesn't appear.

Comment: I'm not useing VSCode's Git, but I bet you get to edit merges only if there are conflicts.

Comment: So... If i'm merging B branch into A branch and I'm the only developer of both branches, it will overrides the A branch with B branch but if B branch is from another developer and I merge it into A branch made by me it will create a conflict and merge editor will open? Sorry I'm a noobie with Git 

Comment: The origin of branch B is totally irrelevant. Only the content changes in the two branches since they diverged are relevant. One example were a conflict arises is when the same line of code was changed in different ways on the two branches. Another is when one branch changed a line, and the other branch changed an adjacent line. Then you must tell what the desired result is. When the branches changed different sections of the code, or one branch did not make a change at all, then no conflict arises and you don't have to edit merge result.

Comment: Mmmm I understand...

I have an app based on React. In A branch I was rendering a component while in B branch I deleted it and I just used a <h1>. When I merged B branch into A branch, the component I was rendering was changed without ask for the <h1>.

I suppose that is because after diverged, A branch didn't have any changes so when B branch was created, that component was replaced by the <h1> and then it just overrided the content of A branch. If I would have made some change in A branch after creating the B branch, a conflict would happen, right?

Comment: That's well possible, provided that the changes in the two branches modify the same lines of code (or adjacent lines). Changes in the same file, but in sections that are separated by lines that remained unmodified on both branches do not create conflicts.